# Cannot access my properties of a class in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I have a problem with my Sharepoint application. I started programming it as a normal project and now I like to “move” it into a Sharepoint application. My app hast two projects one is the actual project for sharepoint and one contains the classes. I signed my classes-project, it has a strong name and is referenced. So far so good… But now I have the problem that I cannot access the public methods within my class anymore. So when instantiate my class:

```
var myName = new ClassName();
```

and later try to access it, for example:

```
myName.Size = 20;
```

“Size” will be marked red with the error “cannot resolve symbol”. But before putting it all into a sharepoint app it worked just fine! I googeld up and down but couldn’t find a solution for this problem.

Does someone know this problem?

UPDATE:

This is my code in the main project:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
  ...

  HPlaner hp = new HPlaner();
  hp.Entries.Add(new HPlanerEntry("Micky Mouse", new DateTime(2012, 12, 24), new DateTime(2013, 1, 13)));

  hp.Scale = 2;
  hp.Year = year;
  hp.Summary = true;
  this.Controls.Add(hp);
}
```

and this is the class:

```
public class HPlaner : WebControl
{
  private List<HPlanerEntry> _Entries;
  public List<HPlanerEntry> Entries
  {
    get
    {
      if (_Entries == null)
      {
        _Entries = new List<HPlanerEntry>();
      }

      return _Entries;
    }
  }

  public bool Summary { get; set; }
  public int Scale { get; set; }
  public int DayCount { get; set; }
  public int UserCount { get; set; }
  public int Year { get; set; }
  public string[,] UserList { get; set; }

  ... (myMethods)

}
```

Comment: Please post all of your code.

Comment: I did add code, but all would be several hundert lines. I hope this is sufficent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, the answer was simple! The Main-Class in the normal project was _Default and in the Sharpoint Application HPlaner, which is the same name as my other class. You could not see this, since the class-name was not inluced in my listing. How timeconsuming can "little" things like that be!!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your code is written targeting x86-architecture while the SharePoint-code target 64-bit. You can change the setting of your code by right-clicking your project in VS and select Properties->Build->Platform Target. Select x64 and recompile.

Comment: Thank you for your input. The projects were set to "Any CPU" i tryed it with x64 and x86 and it did not change the situation.